# Why won’t C compiler give a warning when writing a function which returns nothing and has no side effect?

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

I was debugging a C function that returns nothing (void). At last I found that the function had no side effect (it took a pointer as an argument and changed the pointer itself).

After I found the mistake, I felt confused. Why my compiler gives no warning to this function (even if I use `-Wall` and `-Wextra`)? Obviously this kind of function makes no sense.

Example:

```
void foo(int *a){
    int b[2] = {1, 0};
    a = b;
}
```

It is a useless function and it does nothing actually. But when I use clang and gcc to compile this function with `-Wall -Wextra`, both show no warning and compile normally.

Why? I know that when I use `-O2`, this function will be optimized into a single `ret` instruction, and unused variables and expressions without any side effects will be given warnings (e.g. `int x;` and not using `x` later, or `1 + 1;`)

I have clang 5.0 and gcc 5.4.0

Comment: `It is a wrong function`...why? how? this is 100% correct function. the usability part, well, debatable.

Comment: Why should there be a warning in your opinion? Like you said, it does nothing so you could also say that it isn't doing anything wrong.

Comment: A compiler doesn't have to issue any warnings. The standard may recommend issuing warnings in some cases, but doing that is optional. Also, there's no universal "C compiler", so you should always list the compiler you're using and the version of it.

Comment: OP you talk about pointers, but there are no pointers in the presented code. Did you intend to write `void swap(int* a, int* b) { int tmp = *a; *a = *b; *b = tmp; } ` ?

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: You seem to be looking for code analysis tools (that catch common programming errors like these), but that is not part of the compiler's job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a compiler writer, so not speaking from personal experience, but I think that it's pretty rare for programmers to accidentally write this kind of function. Compiler warnings are for things that are likely to be wrong.

In C, it's fairly common to use conditional compilation. Depending on compile-time option, some code is excluded. It isn't that rare to have a function like this:

```
void cleanup(void) {
#ifdef INCLUDE_FROBNICATOR
     frob_close();
#endif
#ifdef INCLUDE_WIDGET_HANDLER
     for (size_t i = 0; i < WIDGET_COUNT; i++)
         destroy_widget(widgets[i]);
     }
#endif
}
```

If none of the optional features are included, then the function does nothing. But this is perfectly legitimate code and the author wouldn't appreciate a warning here.

Conditional compilation and more generally use of the preprocessor is a big reason why compilers don't emit warnings if they notice that a piece of code gets optimized away. If a task can be entirely performed at compile time, that's great! Less time to spend during execution, no risk of failure. Another reason why warnings are often not based on the result of optimization is that the warnings can be very hard to understand because the optimized code doesn't have the same structure as the source code. Most warning are based on an intermediate stage where the code still broadly looks like the source.

Compilers *do* warn about useless things sometimes, but it's a compromise between warning about cases where the programmer has forgotten something, and warning about things that were legitimately optimized at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't necessary for a compiler to issue you a warning because the code does not violate any grammar rules.

In C, an expression that does nothing (like `1+1;`) is basically an "unused expression" which well complies to the rule, so it isn't even mandatory to issue a warning for that! Support for such warnings is optional. It's all up to the compiler.

For "useless" functions, they are more complicated than "useless" expressions. So *maybe* the compiler believes that no one accidentally writes useless functions, so it does not give a warning.